# Why is there different shading on the same material

Tags: materials, shaders

I’ve been learning blender and am currently modeling my phone for practice. I have two problems, which I suspect both have to do with shading, and have thus placed them in one post.

1. One of the triangles in the glass is randomly lighter than the surrounding area, and there are no defined edges along it.
2. The center polygons of the phone’s bottom edge are not being shaded (I think?) correctly. The whole bottom edge is the same material and is all smoothly shaded.

Pictures:
[image: Rendered][image: Wireframe]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks everyone!

Comment: Thats not different shading, its just shadow, it looks like your sun is perpendicular to the part where yours speakers and USB type C are located. Take your sun at top that is over the screen, maintain some distance of the sun from the screen and now shading will be swapped and this is common in real world too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the flat faces:

- Select the flat faces in edit mode and set shading to smooth
- Check your auto-smooth settings (under Mesh properties -> Normals)

For the other face, It looks like you have an N-gon (a face with more than 4 edges). N-gons tend to triangulate poorly and so can lead to shading artifacts, particularly when they are not convex like the one you have. You need to break this up into simpler faces.